# Winnovative - Parse excel file with hyperlink fails (xls only)

Tags: c#, excel, xls, winnovative

Using Winnovative's excel library I am able to parse an excel file (xls) that contains a hyperlink. It works when the program is run directly on my machine. The exact same file will fail if I try to upload it to a website and parse it. Here is an example of the logic:

```
// Works when bytes are parsed from a program running locally.
// Fails when bytes are parsed from a file uploaded to a website
public void TestRead(byte[] bytes)
{
    try
    {
        // Parse excel file
        var workBook = new ExcelWorkbook(new MemoryStream(bytes));

        // Save file
        var toSave = workBook.Save();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\[User]\Downloads\Test.xls", toSave);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

This is only an issue with `xls` files. I don't have trouble parsing a `xlsx` file with a hyperlink. The uploaded file fails to parse with an exception (which also crashes the application even though it is enclosed in a `try-catch` block):

> Could not open the workbook.Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
>
> at Winnovative.ExcelLib.ExcelWorkbook..ctor(Stream excelStream, String openPassword, ExcelWorkbookDefaultSettings defaultSettings)
>      at Winnovative.ExcelLib.ExcelWorkbook..ctor(Stream excelStream)

and

> System.OverflowException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in wnvxls.dll
>   Additional information: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @tube-builder I have not.

Comment: If you're interested, my solution was to change the “Enable 32-bit Applications” to True in the IIS Application Pool advanced settings. Perhaps this will help you.

Comment: @tube-builder, interesting! Thank you for the tip.

Comment: If someone experiences the same problem when running in debug in VS2022, here's a solution: open Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects and uncheck Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects.